# Word Vector Features preprocessing for ML

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, word2vec, data-preprocessing

I'm training a classifier, where the input is a 300-dimensional word vector.
Usually in machine learning problems, I would scale my inputs to 0-mean and unit variance.

However, scaling the vector inputs in this manner changes their relative similarity, as below:

```
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Normalizer

def cos_sim(a, b):
    return dot(a, b.T)/(norm(a)*norm(b))

unscaled = cos_sim(X[301, :].reshape(1,-1), X[302, :].reshape(1,-1))
ss = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = ss.fit_transform(X)
scaled = cos_sim(X_scaled[301, :].reshape(1,-1), X_scaled[302, :].reshape(1,-1))


print(f'unscaled = {unscaled} \n scaled = {scaled}')

>>> unscaled = [[0.72310966]] 
 scaled = scaled = [[-0.2791]]
```

Which (apart from sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) are standard steps of preprocessing these kinds of inputs for standard downstream ML problems, such as (multi-class) classification?

Comment: [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) is another standard approach.

Comment: MinMaxScaler also changes the cosine similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Did scaling them in a way that changes their relative similarities improve your classification results, or worsen them?

If it improves the classification results, why would you be concerned that it also changes their cosine similarity? There's nothing sacred about their original pairwise similarities, except that they were useful for some purposes.

Conversely, if your scaling worsens the classification results, I don't think you'd want to do it, even if it's your usual approach, or widely-practiced.

And that goes for any other "standard steps of processing" anyone might suggest. Merely that they're *often* used, and *sometimes* helpful, shouldn't override your own evaluations of whether they're helping in *your* particular dataset/domain/task.

There's a paper, [All-but-the-Top: Simple and Effective Postprocessing for Word Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01417), that suggests word-vectors generally *improve* if you re-center them around the origin (remove the common mean as your `StandardScaler` does), and do some other adjustments (but *not* necessarily unit-normalization). Figuratively, if I understand correctly, those help increase the remaining 'contrast' – and yes, changing pairwise cosine-similarities.

And yet, those sorts of word-vector adjustments don't seem to be widely done in published work – perhaps because people have an undue reverence for the unaltered output of standard popular algorithms, or for the exact values of popular pretrained sets of word-vectors.

So, your usual habit may have already tended towards better results than 'standard' practice.

(But: I'd be wary of the unit-normalization, and check whether that's helping or hurting your classification results separately. In some cases, the magnitude of word-vectors is a useful signal of the strength/clarity of their meaning, & depending on your downstream classifier, might prove relevant in its calculations.)